# Updating cider to 20180624 hangs while compiling

Tags: package-repositories, cider

When upgrading cider, emacs hangs while compiling cider-repl-handle-shortcut:

[image: cider upgrade hangs]

I am running emacs 25.3~1.gite0284ab-kk1+16 on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

The compile log buffer after C-g shows:

```
Compiling file /home/aschmitz/.emacs.d/elpa/cider-20180624.2344/cider-repl.el at Tue Jun 26 10:00:53 2018

Compiling no file at Tue Jun 26 10:07:48 2018
Warning: ‘0’ is a malformed function
Warning: ‘(nil)’ is a malformed function
Warning: ‘(t)’ is a malformed function
Warning: ‘special-display-function’ is an obsolete variable (as of 24.3); use
    ‘display-buffer-alist’ instead.
Warning: ‘special-display-function’ is an obsolete variable (as of 24.3); use
    ‘display-buffer-alist’ instead.
Warning: Use ‘with-current-buffer’ rather than save-excursion+set-buffer
```

How can I recover from this? Aborting and retrying does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that cider 20180628 fixed this.

see for example:

https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/commit/ad68a5616d6bbd6d8dde6c38e0bbda63d222ca1f